# Перевод секунд в дату от рождества Хр

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в java перевести строку 63672393600 в дату, чтобы не придумывать велосипед?

Строка - это дата в секундах от рождества Христова.

результат должен получиться - 2018-09-13 12:26:42 (это данные из базы, из которой вытянули данные с этой датой и конвертировали в секунды).

Comment: я ни чего не понимаю в java но вроде бы исчисление времени идёт в unixtimespamp т.е день рождение unix

Comment: Знаю, но нужно перевести именно от рождества.

Comment: да какой-то бред с добавлениями, вычитаниями получается

Comment: число секунд в дне кратно 100, на входе число у вас также кратно 100. Откуда на выходе у вас 42 секунды взялись? День рождения с точностью до секунды разве известно? Если использовать proleptic gregorian календарь, результат 2018-09-13 (ровно). На Питоне: `>>> DT.datetime.min+DT.timedelta(seconds=63672393600)
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 13, 0, 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(1, Month.JANUARY, 1, 12, 26, 42);
LocalDateTime resDate = ldt.plusSeconds(63672393600L);
System.out.println("resDate = " + resDate);
```

Вывод:

```
resDate = 2018-09-13T12:26:42
```

Как правильно заметил комментатор @default locale@, непонятно почему время не 00:00. Если считать, что Хр родился в 12:26:42, тогда все сходится.

Comment: Видимо так и было :)) у меня тоже подозрение, что в секунды конвертировали с ошибкой

Comment: Да, так и оказалось, изначально неправильно переводилось время в секунды.

Comment: Добрый день, Алексей. Может еще подскажете, как из Date перевести в секунды, чтобы отсчет был от (1, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, 0) ?

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский Не совсем понял вопрос. Дата хранится в миллисекундах, если нужны секунды - делите на 1000.

Comment: в миллисекундах отсчет идет от UNIX времени (от 01.01.1970). А нужно, чтобы дату, например 2018-12-26 11:39:27 перевести в секунды. И чтобы следующий метод мог воспроизвести обратно:

Comment: описал в новой теме - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941590/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-date-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-java

Answer (score 1):

Ну если грубо, то как-то так:

```
long seconds = 63672393600L;
//первое число первого месяца первого года
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1, 0, 1);
//метод add не работает с long, поэтому переводим в миллисекунды для добавления
calendar.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis()+seconds*1000);
Date date = calendar.getTime(); //11.09.2018
```

Вы не написали, какой календарь нужно использовать для рассчетов. В Java [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) использует гибридный: с переходом с юлианского на григорианский в октябре 1582-го. Если нужен другой расчет, то потребуются уточнения. (Про часовые пояса я даже не говорю).

Демонстрация на ideone: https://ideone.com/sRWAS4

Comment: Нет никакой информации по переходам и и часовых поясах. Дата должна получиться вот такая 2018-09-13 12:26:42

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский Ну ОК, попробуйте код. Я просто не знаю для каких целей он Вам нужен поэтому счел нужным предупредить о возможных нюансах

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский Если знаете какой нужен результат, то укажите его в вопросе и расскажите почему он именно такой. P.S. 63672393600 секунд = 736949*24*3600 = 736949 суток. Странно, что у Вас дата не соответствует полночи. Расскажите как так получается

Comment: Спасибо, внес уточнения в вопрос. Как так получается, к сожалению информации нет.

Comment: Как раз сегодня делал учебный материал по `java.time` и вот на реальном примере вижу насколько чудовищно отличается результат при использовании устаревших классов `Date`  и`Calendar`! Разница в 2 дня и 1 час (в ответе, кстати, не просто 11 сентября 2018, а еще и время 01:00:00)

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець Действительно, разумнее было начать с `java.time`, +1. Времени только я не увидел: https://ideone.com/sRWAS4

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець [разница в двое суток](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar#Difference_between_Julian_and_proleptic_Gregorian_calendar_dates) в данном случае не баг. Просто старые классы используют для данного периода юлианский календарь, а новые — предваряющий григорианский.

Comment: Я думал, эти календари отличаются на 13 дней

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець это сейчас. На момент перехода (1582) разница была 10 дней. Если продолжить григорианский назад до введения (предваряющий григорианский календарь), то в 1 г. н.э. разница будет двое суток.

Comment: Круто. Я не знал. Как полезно