# Как перевести дату и время из Date в секунды от рождества Христова в Java?

Tags: java, дата, localdate

Как перевести дату и время из `Date` в секунды от рождества Христова?

`date.getTime()` - возвращает от начала *UNIX* времени.

Нужно например 2018-12-26 11:39:27 перевести в секунды от 01.01.0001 00:00:00

Уточнение:
Корректнее будет использовать не Date, а Timestamp 
Есть сервис которому нужно передать дату и время в секундах. Этот сервис следующим методом воспроизводит из секунд обратно в дату и время:

```
 private String dateConverter(String date) {
            LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(1, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            LocalDateTime resDate = ldt.plusSeconds(Long.parseLong(date));
            return String.valueOf(resDate);
        }
```

соответственно дату и время (например 2018-12-26 11:39:27) нужно предварительно перевести в секунды, с началом исчисления от 01.01.0001 00:00:00

Comment: Рождество Христова - это когда? 00.00.0000?

Comment: думаю это 01.01.0001 00:00:00

Comment: Что Вы собираетесь с этим числом делать?

Comment: передавать в другой сервис, который требует такой формат

Comment: Я бы наверное раз 5 переспросил у разработчиков того сервиса что это именно так. вдруг они unixtime так назвали. Если конечно это не какой то исторический сервис, которому надо передавать время до 70 года

Comment: @AntonSorokin Даты 00.00.0000 не существует :) Нулевого года (как и месяца, и дня) нет. После 1 г. до н.э. идет 1 г. н.э.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну хорошо, тогда 01.01.0001.

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский В любом случае узнайте у разработчиков того сервиса сколько секунд у них прошло до 1970 года. потому что могут быть разные мнения и методики расчета этого значения

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что Иисус родился позже «рождества Христова»?) Так что уточняйте, пожалуйста, в вопросе конкретные данные

Comment: Да и время до 1970 года никто не мешает передавать отрицательным числом.

Comment: А у такого сервиса должен быть механизм, который этот обратный перевод осуществляет на их стороне, надо узнать какая там реализация, особенно если по ту сторону алгоритм перевода был получен так же, как вы его пытаетесь получить :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот такой код возвращает то, что вам надо:

```
    ZonedDateTime localNow = 
        Instant.now().atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault());
    ZonedDateTime localAtCristsBirth = 
        Instant.parse("0001-01-01T00:00:00.00Z").atZone(ZoneOffset.systemDefault());
    Duration timePassed = Duration.between(localAtCristsBirth, localNow);
    System.out.format("От тождества Христова прошло %d секунд\n", 
        timePassed.getSeconds() );
```

**Уточнение** в ответ на уточнение в вопросе:

Фактически код, который вы привели, не учитывает временных зон, то есть конвертирует количество секунд, прошедших с момента `0001.01.01 00:00` по местному времени (не важно, какому именно) в дату по тому же самому местному времени. Если это называть количеством секунд "от рождества Христова", то этот код можно признать правильным только в том часовом поясе, в котором Иисус родился. 
Вот код, который получает `Timestamp` *(раз уж вам так хочется, хотя я не понимаю, зачем вам тут вообще нужен `Date` или "более корректный" `Timestamp`)* и возвращает именно то, что вам надо (кол-во секунд с `00:00 01.01.01` местного времени в виде строки):

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Ru_so_941590 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timestamp now = Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()); 
        say("Местное время:   " + now);
        String secondsAD_str = secsWouldHavePassedSinceChtistsBirthIfHeHadBeenBornHere(now);
        System.out.format("Если бы Спаситель родился здесь, "
                + "то с момента его рождения прошло бы\n\t\t %,d секунд\n", 
                Long.parseLong(secondsAD_str) );
        say("Converted back:  " + dateStrFromSecondsAD(secondsAD_str));
    }

    private static String secsWouldHavePassedSinceChtistsBirthIfHeHadBeenBornHere(Timestamp now) {
        LocalDateTime nowLocal = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(now.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        LocalDateTime christsBirthday = LocalDateTime.parse("0001-01-01T00:00:00");
        return String.valueOf(Duration.between(christsBirthday, nowLocal).getSeconds());
    }

     private static String dateStrFromSecondsAD(String secondStr) {
         LocalDateTime christsBirth = LocalDateTime.of(1, Month.JANUARY, 1, 0, 0, 0);
         LocalDateTime resDate = christsBirth.plusSeconds(Long.parseLong(secondStr));
         return String.valueOf(resDate);
     }

    static void say(String format, Object... args) { System.out.println(String.format(format, args)); }
    static void say(String s) { System.out.println(s); }
}
```

Comment: В разных часовых поясах одинаковый результат будет?

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, конечно. Если строго от рождения Христа, надо выяснить, в каком часовом поясе он родился :)

Comment: В [UTC+2](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BC), конечно же :)

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну вообще-то, конечно, логичней считать, что он родился по гринвичскому времени :) Тогда для второго `ZonedDateTime` надо указать UTC.

Comment: Вместо Date использовал Timestamp, так корректнее.               
ZonedDateTime localNow = timestampDate.toInstant().atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() ) ; Далее все по вашему описанию. Но получается разница в 2 часа при обратной конвертации методом из описания.

Comment: Установил ZoneId.of("-00:00") вместо ZoneOffset.systemDefault() - и теперь все ок

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский "получается разница в 2 часа"  Ну правильно, она и должна получаться. `localAtCristsBirth` в моем коде -- это местное время в момент рождения Христа (в предположении, что он родился в 0 часов по Гринвичу). Вы можете вывести его на консоль, и увидите, что это просто смещение вашего пояса относительно UTC. А ваш код обратного преобразования не учитывает временной пояс, т. е. фактически возвращает гринвичское время, а не местное. Если вы в Москве, момент рождения Христа будет в 3 часа ночи, разница будет 0 секунд, и ваш код вернет 00:00 вместо ожидаемых 03:00.

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский см. дополненный ответ